# Does gsutil rsync bucket1 bucket2 download/upload files locally?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a dumb question.

So I have terrabytes of data to rsync between two GCP buckets.

I'm not too sure with how `gsutil rsync` works behind the scenes.

Does it have to download the files locally before it uploads it to destination or does it just magically move things over from source bucket to destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I performed a test with `RSYNC` and the debug flags and I noticed this behaviour

When you move an object (using cp or rsync) between buckets **this is not downloaded to your local machine**, I used a file of ~4GB and `glances` to measure the network usage during rsync operation, the objects were directly moved to the target bucket

If you run the following command you going to notice that the SDK perform a post request indicating the movement between buckets

`gsutil -d rsync gs://sourcebucket gs://targetbucket`

```
https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/sourcebucket/o/bigfile.iso/rewriteTo/b/targetbucket/o/bigfile.iso
```

`Rewriteto` behaviour is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/rewrite)

Comment: you are right. I would be careful with `-d` though it deletes whatever's not in source

Comment: `gsutil -d` is debug flag of gsutil , if you put `-d` after rsync works as you mention

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is in the [gsutil rsync documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync):

> Note 2: If you are synchronizing a large amount of data between clouds you might consider setting up a Google Compute Engine account and running gsutil there. **Since cross-provider gsutil data transfers flow through the machine where gsutil is running**, doing this can make your transfer run significantly faster than running gsutil on your local workstation.

So yes, it downloads the content locally first, then uploads it to the destination.

Comment: but this is cross provider right? So if its GCP -> GCP then it shouldn't have to download it

Comment: That depends on if each bucket is considered its own provider, I suppose.  You could measure this yourself by looking at the network stats on your machine as you run the command.